# Failed to list gulp tasks in WebStorm 2016.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, webstorm

I am using Gulp 3.9.1, node 5.7.1, npm 3.10.3, and WebStorm 2016.1.  When I try to setup gulp for my project, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/msbauer/Developer/workspaces/provider-data-management/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js --color --gulpfile /Users/msbauer/Developer/workspaces/provider-data-management/gulpfile.js

  error: unknown option `--color'


Process finished with exit code 1
```

And when I force to rescan tasks:

```
Failed to list gulp tasks in provider-data-management/gulpfile.js: process finished with exit code 1 (a non-zero exit code means an error)
 * Edit settings

$ /usr/local/bin/node /Users/msbauer/Developer/workspaces/provider-data-management/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js --no-color --gulpfile /Users/msbauer/Developer/workspaces/provider-data-management/gulpfile.js --tasks

  error: unknown option `--no-color'


Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I execute `gulp --help` at CLI:

```
$ gulp --help

  Usage: gulp [options] [command]


  Commands:

    about   display version information about availity-workflow project
    init    initialize project metadata: package.json, bower.json, availity.json and README.md

  Options:

    -h, --help     output usage information
    -V, --version  output the version number
```

It's almost as if WebStorm is tacking on extra params, but the version of gulp I have doesn't support said params.

**Updated:**

I ran the following to installed gulp-cli (the second from my project root):

```
$ brew install gulp-cli
$ npm install -g gulp-cli
```

If I do `gulp --help` I get the right options:

```
$ gulp --help

Usage: gulp [options] tasks

Options:
  --help, -h       Show this help.                                     [boolean]
  --version, -v    Print the global and local gulp versions.           [boolean]
  --require        Will require a module before running the gulpfile. This is
                   useful for transpilers but also has other applications.
                                                                        [string]
  --gulpfile       Manually set path of gulpfile. Useful if you have multiple
                   gulpfiles. This will set the CWD to the gulpfile directory as
                   well.                                                [string]
  --cwd            Manually set the CWD. The search for the gulpfile, as well as
                   the relativity of all requires will be from here.    [string]
  --verify         Will verify plugins referenced in project's package.json
                   against the plugins blacklist.
  --tasks, -T      Print the task dependency tree for the loaded gulpfile.
                                                                       [boolean]
  --depth          Specify the depth of the task dependency tree.
  --tasks-simple   Print a plaintext list of tasks for the loaded gulpfile.
                                                                       [boolean]
  --tasks-json     Print the task dependency tree, in JSON format, for the
                   loaded gulpfile.
  --color          Will force gulp and gulp plugins to display colors, even when
                   no color support is detected.                       [boolean]
  --no-color       Will force gulp and gulp plugins to not display colors, even
                   when color support is detected.                     [boolean]
  --silent, -S     Suppress all gulp logging.                          [boolean]
  --continue       Continue execution of tasks upon failure.           [boolean]
  --log-level, -L  Set the loglevel. -L for least verbose and -LLLL for most
                   verbose. -LLL is default.                             [count]
```

`which` returns the path `/Users/me/Developer/homebrew/bin/gulp`.  But if I run `gulp --color` I still get the error `error: unknown option`--color'`

If I do the same experiment using the gulp path of `~/Developer/workspace/project/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js --help`(again, from CLI) I get the exact same results: `--help` outputs the correct options, but `--color` and `--no-color` fails with the same error, despite being listed as valid options.

Comment: I'm not actually gulp user myself (yet -- just starting to learn/use it) .. but I've installed `gulp-cli` (globally; as per [official documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md)) and it's v1.2.1 (latest version). If I do `gulp --help` .. I do see different output where `--color` option **is supported**. I believe your `gulp` is just gulp itself while you also need `gulp-cli` (and that's what IDE must be using to run gulp tasks). **P.S.** node 4.4.4; npm 2.15.1 (bundled one).

Comment: That was it!  Add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I take it back.  It added the options when I do `--help` from CLI, but if I actually try to run it from CLI or from WebStorm, I still get the same error

Comment: So it must be calling wrong `gulp.js` -- see if you can specify correct path there. BTW -- have you tried restarting IDE after that? It may simply still use old one (old PATH). Try in brand new project as well (with simplest task possible -- just to see what result would be).

Comment: P.S. You can also upgrade to the latest stable WebStorm 2016.2 (released just yesterday or day before that). Maybe it will execute different command with no `--color` option?

Comment: I set the path to the one in my project, current's `~/me/Developer/workspace/project/node_modules/gulp-cli`.  I did try quitting and restarting WS.  The strange thing is that doing `gulp --help` from cli shows the options, but if I pass `--help` in WS's run config it does not.  Also, if I run from cli with `--color` I get the same error, despite it listing the option as part of the `--help` output

Comment: No other ideas from me, sorry. Maybe JetBrains folks can help -- they visit SO often (at least once a day). If no feedback from them: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200367229-WebStorm or  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB (last one is for actual bugs/feature requests and not "I have a question" or "how to")

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue just now. I tracked it down to a part of our app creating a custom CLI using commander.js. I was able to tell commander to pass along the options needed. I will have to send a pull request over instead of hacking up the node_modules version.

*project* gulpfile.js:

```
var cli = require('custom-cli');
```

*Project*\node_modules\custom-cli\cli\index.js

```
var program = require('commander');

program.version(manifests.package.json.version);

//WebStorm needs to pass these options to gulp, so commander has to know about them
program.option('--no-color', 'Disable Colors');
program.option('--gulpfile', 'gulpfile');
```