# Gulp shows options for --color and --no-color, but errors when you use them

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am new to gulp, running CLI version 1.2.1 and Local 3.9.1.  I am trying to get it to run in WebStore 2016.1, but I am getting an error in both trying to run the default task and in getting the task list.

The issue is that the IDE appears to be trying to tack on `--color` for running the gulp task and `--no-color` when it tries to get the list of tasks.  From command line, if I run `gulp --help` I see the two flags plain as day:

```
$ gulp --help

Usage: gulp [options] tasks

Options:
  --help, -h       Show this help.                                     [boolean]
  --version, -v    Print the global and local gulp versions.           [boolean]
  --require        Will require a module before running the gulpfile. This is
                   useful for transpilers but also has other applications.
                                                                        [string]
  --gulpfile       Manually set path of gulpfile. Useful if you have multiple
                   gulpfiles. This will set the CWD to the gulpfile directory as
                   well.                                                [string]
  --cwd            Manually set the CWD. The search for the gulpfile, as well as
                   the relativity of all requires will be from here.    [string]
  --verify         Will verify plugins referenced in project's package.json
                   against the plugins blacklist.
  --tasks, -T      Print the task dependency tree for the loaded gulpfile.
                                                                       [boolean]
  --depth          Specify the depth of the task dependency tree.
  --tasks-simple   Print a plaintext list of tasks for the loaded gulpfile.
                                                                       [boolean]
  --tasks-json     Print the task dependency tree, in JSON format, for the
                   loaded gulpfile.
  --color          Will force gulp and gulp plugins to display colors, even when
                   no color support is detected.                       [boolean]
  --no-color       Will force gulp and gulp plugins to not display colors, even
                   when color support is detected.                     [boolean]
  --silent, -S     Suppress all gulp logging.                          [boolean]
  --continue       Continue execution of tasks upon failure.           [boolean]
  --log-level, -L  Set the loglevel. -L for least verbose and -LLLL for most
                   verbose. -LLL is default.                             [count]
```

And if I run `./node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js --help` I get the exact same output:

```
$ ./node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js --help

Usage: gulp [options] tasks

Options:
  --help, -h       Show this help.                                     [boolean]
  --version, -v    Print the global and local gulp versions.           [boolean]
  --require        Will require a module before running the gulpfile. This is
                   useful for transpilers but also has other applications.
                                                                        [string]
  --gulpfile       Manually set path of gulpfile. Useful if you have multiple
                   gulpfiles. This will set the CWD to the gulpfile directory as
                   well.                                                [string]
  --cwd            Manually set the CWD. The search for the gulpfile, as well as
                   the relativity of all requires will be from here.    [string]
  --verify         Will verify plugins referenced in project's package.json
                   against the plugins blacklist.
  --tasks, -T      Print the task dependency tree for the loaded gulpfile.
                                                                       [boolean]
  --depth          Specify the depth of the task dependency tree.
  --tasks-simple   Print a plaintext list of tasks for the loaded gulpfile.
                                                                       [boolean]
  --tasks-json     Print the task dependency tree, in JSON format, for the
                   loaded gulpfile.
  --color          Will force gulp and gulp plugins to display colors, even when
                   no color support is detected.                       [boolean]
  --no-color       Will force gulp and gulp plugins to not display colors, even
                   when color support is detected.                     [boolean]
  --silent, -S     Suppress all gulp logging.                          [boolean]
  --continue       Continue execution of tasks upon failure.           [boolean]
  --log-level, -L  Set the loglevel. -L for least verbose and -LLLL for most
                   verbose. -LLL is default.                             [count]
```

also, if I add `--help` to the arguments in WebStorm I get the same output.  So, from a help standpoint, it "thinks" it has the options available.

However, if I try to run the app from WebStorm I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/me/Developer/workspaces/project/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js --color --gulpfile /Users/me/Developer/workspaces/projects/gulpfile.js --color

  error: unknown option `--color'


Process finished with exit code 1
```

and if I run `gulp --color` or `./node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js --color` I get the error `error: unknown option '--color'`

And if I try to tell WebStorm to refresh the tasks, I get a similar error `error: unknown option '--no-color'`.

I am not sure why the help shows the option as availiable, but trying to use the flag(s) doesn't work.

For reference, I also opened [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356822/failed-to-list-gulp-tasks-in-webstorm-2016-1) asking the question from a WebStorm-perspective.

Comment: For those few that have stopped by with the same problem, I really wish I had an answer.  I posted on the gulp-cli Github hoping someone there could help, but was told it's probably due to a mis-match of gulp vs. gulp-cli, and my issue was closed.  Without a version matrix, though, I am not sure which versions I should be looking for.  If I ever get time to just monkey around with getting this to work I'll post a solution, but for now I have found other ways to work around my issues.